# Compilation Error while using ChainLink

Tags: remix, cpp-ethereum, compilation, chainlink

I am using Remix IDE for my smart contract development. I am using the following import line

`import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";`

But I am getting this error while compilation

`DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. setPublicChainlinkToken();`

The entire code is:

````
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract VersionControl {
    
    struct Asset {
        uint256 id;
        string name;
        string metadata;
        string ipfsHash;
        uint256 version;
        
        bool isPresent;
        
        mapping (address => uint256) contribution;
    }
    
    mapping (uint256 => Asset) assets;
                
    address tokenAddress;
    address owner;
    uint256 availabeId;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        availabeId = 0;
        
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e;
        jobId = "29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
        
    }
    
    // function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    // {
    //     Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
    //     // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
    //     request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        
    //     // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
    //     // {"RAW":
    //     //   {"ETH":
    //     //    {"USD":
    //     //     {
    //     //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
    //     //     }
    //     //    }
    //     //   }
    //     //  }
    //     request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
        
    //     // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
    //     int timesAmount = 10**18;
    //     request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
    //     // Sends the request
    //     return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    // }
    
    
}```

Ignore the requestVolumeData as it will be the place where I call the 3rd Party APIs
````

Comment: Actually, I can't seem to reproduce this error. Could you edit the question to send the full constructor/method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inherit the `ChainlinkClient`into your contract.

Change your contract line from:

```
contract VersionControl {
```

to

```
contract VersionControl is ChainlinkClient {
```